# How to work around the can't cast from parent to child issue

Tags: c#

i have read about the reason why you can't cast a parent to a child: you can't cast an ANIMAL to a DOG; it might be a CAT.

But here is my issue:

i receive a data object from my datalayer with 50 properties. Now i created a child object of this object, with only one more property.

And in my function, i want to fill all the 51 properties of my object with the 50 of the base object, and the one extra.

So i'm looking for a way to 'copy' the 50 properties of the parent object to the child object.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the base copy constructor via the child object's initializer list?

Comment: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You can write out 50 assignments, or do a loop with Reflection. But first make sure that inheritance is the right model here.

Comment: @MGZero: the copy constructor would make me assign 50 properties? Besides looking as the work i'm trying to avoid, wouldn't that lead to possible problems when the baseobject is extended and the copy-code is forgotten?

Comment: @Henk: as you might guess, the 50 assignments is something i want to avoid.

Comment: @Michel I'm confused.  You want to copy 50 properties, but you want to avoid assigning them?

Comment: How are you getting the data into the parent class object?

Comment: @MGZero i want to not exactly 'copy' them, but i have one object with 50 props and another, almost the same, object and it feels needless to create code to manually copy properties from object A to object B when i have said "B is like A, plus a little extra"

Comment: @mydogisbox the parent object is filled by a custom made data layer (from generated code which reads a sqlreader via a sqlcommand in the object)

Comment: @MattDavey Thought of Automapper. Don't know why, but it seems like an overkill to add an extra dependency / DLL for this simple task. But that is not only for this scenario, i'm not quick with using 3rd party tools which i don't know for tasks that have a work around (which the copy properties feels like)

Comment: @Michel I agree and personally I don't like Automapper and I don't usually recommend it. But I'm guessing by the fact that you have 50+ properties on a class that this class is either a DTO or an ActiveRecord like object, in which case Automapper (or my personal preference ValueInjecter) may be appropriate. If that's not the case then I'd say your question here is a symptom of a rather more fundamental OO design problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very possibly a time where you don't want to use inheritance.  To do this have the new Type not inherit from anything and have two properties, one being of the old type (what you're currently considering using as the parent) and another with the new piece of data.

Comment: Thought of that too. First thing that came to my mind was that it would give me a hard time with the databinding, because i now have to bind to a 'subobject'. But besides that, i am very curious (in a positive way) why this isn't a case for inheritance.

Comment: @Michel It's not a case for inheritance because it would require you to copy 50 values from one class to another just so you can store one additional property.  It's much easier both to code, and to run, to have an object that 'add to' or 'decorates' another object by storing both it and some small amount of additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of copy constructors to create new child objects based on parent objects.  You could even create a copy constructor in the parent class and utilize that constructor when creating a new child.

```
public Parent (Parent other)
{
   //copy other.Properties to this.Properties
}


public Child (Parent other) : base(other)
{
   //populate property 51
}

public Child (Child other) : base(other)
{
   //copy property 51
}
```

If you're looking to copy properties to an existing instance, you'll probably need to create a separate method for that.

```
public void Assimilate(Parent other)
{
   //copy parent's properties
}

public void Assimilate(Child other)
{
   //copy child's properties
}
```

Comment: To make sure that i understand this: this would make me write code like this: thisba = other.a, this.b = other.b etc?

Comment: Right.  There's no easy way around that when creating copy methods. It's the price you pay for having classes with many properties. Unless you use something like AutoMapper.

Comment: Ah, at least you understand my needs: looking for an easy way :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approachs to a generic solution (i.e one that does not involve a manual copy of each property and the associated maintanance nightmare) based on a copy constructor:

1. Make a shallow copy using reflection.  [Example here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4683-Copy-Constructor-C-using-Reflection.aspx)
2. Make a deep copy using serialization (serialize your base object into a memory stream and then serialize out of that into your derived object). First part of [example here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2009/07/17/implement-copy-constructor-using-serialization-or-reflecton.aspx) discusses serialization (article discusses both approaches).

Answer (score 0):

This is to the side of your question (the copy constructor answer seems one possible way to go), but note that you *can* cast from a base class to a sub-class, but that it's just not guaranteed to succeed like casting from a sub-class to a base.  See below:

```
public class Base
{
}

public class Child1 : Base
{
}

public class Child2 : Base
{
}

main()
{
    Child1 ch1 = new Child1();
    Child2 ch2 = new Child2();

    Base myBase;
    myBase = ch1; // Always succeeds, no cast required
    myBase = ch2; // Always succeeds, no cast required

    // myBase contains ch2, of type Child2
    Child1 tmp1;
    Child2 tmp2;

    tmp2 = (Child2)myBase;   // succeeds, but dangerous
    tmp2 = mybase as Child2; // succeeds, but safer, since "as" operator returns null if the cast is invalid
    tmp1 = (Child1)myBase;   // throws a ClassCastException and tmp1 is still unassigned
    tmp1 = myBase as Child1; // tmp1 is now null, no exception thrown

    if(myBase is Child1)     
    {
        tmp1 = (Child1)myBase; // safe now, as the conditional has said it's true
    }
    if(myBase is Child2)     // test to see if the object is the sub-class or not
    {
        tmp2 = (Child2)myBase; // safe now, as the conditional has said it's true
    } 
}
```

I hope that makes sense.  If you just cast it blindly, it can throw an exception.  If you use the `as` keyword, it will either succeed, or return null.  Or you can "test" it beforehand with an if-statement and the `is` keyword prior to assigning it.